# Laravel global search (multiple models)

Tags: sql, laravel, search, scope, eloquent

I'm changing my search system to global(In multiple model). Now, it's searching perfectly in the just one model. But, i am trying to make this global search. I mean global search is "**search in multiple tables**". Working codes are here:

```
public function scopeSearch(Builder $query, $search)
    {
        $query->whereHas('translations', function ($q) use ($search) {
            $q->where('value', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
        })
            ->orWhere('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
            ->orWhere('sub_body', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
            ->orWhere('body', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
    }
```

This is searching in the model and the connected translations tables (translated values for the existing value. There is no problem with that.)

I need to add something like that. Or whatever you suggest.

```
whereHas('2nd_table', function ($q) use ($search) {
$q->where('title', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');})
```

Comment: `whereHas` works with relational data, `2nd_table` is relational data?

Comment: No, this is the actual problem. Sorry about that, i should have mentioned it before.

Comment: then what about join? you can use DB join for that.

Comment: Can you give me a little simple? Because i couldn't make it.

Comment: check code [sample](https://kopy.io/0YHAp)